# Heating and insulation of Hogwarts castle?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Since Hogwarts is a castle what kind of heating system (if any) do they have (besides fireplaces of course) and do the fireplaces put out heat or is Floo Powder different due to people coming in or making personal calls?

From the pictures I've seen the Gryffindor tower looks like a central stove of some sorts which doesn't look very good but at least it can't be spied on by people or agencies thru (Smart) technology or remotely controlled :)

Do you suppose Hogwarts has good insulation or do you think it's equal to a northern California home where during a cold wave below 32F you can put your hands to an outlet and feel the cold coming thru it?

I bet those little Gryffindors wake up like Popsickles during a polar cold wave and some politically correct parent is going sue Dumbledore for bad heating because of their little demons getting colds all year long.   Hope the place isn't full of asbestos either.

Do you think Hogwarts passes the heating inspection test or do you think it gets a big F (close it down) or perhaps a C (okay but needs LOTS of improvement your crossing the line there)

Comment: Exempt from regulations due to historical nature of the building.

Answer (score 3):

### Umm.. Magic!

There are spells to keep corridors and dormitories warm. I would assume the Hogwarts staff and heads of the houses took care of it. Moreover corridors and Great Hall are lined with flaming torches and candles etc, which would also provide heat. Also, chores like cleaning and keeping the dormitories comfortable for students was done by house elves.

> Harry, Ron, and Neville got into their pajamas and into bed. **Someone -
> a house- elf, no doubt - had placed warming pans between the sheets.**
> It was extremely comfortable, lying there in bed and listening to the
> storm raging outside.
>
> *Goblet of fire: Chapter 12, The Triwizard Tournament*

Its safe to assume that classroom temperatures are taken care of by individual teachers because I remember two specific occasions where it was mentioned in the books;

- one where Harry mentions that Potions classes were exceptionally cold during winter because they were in dungeons. (I'll try to find the quote from the book as I don't remember which book.)
- one where Professor Trelawney's class was very hot because she never opens windows and always has fire on in her classrooms.

> "It's going to be boiling in Trelawney's room, she never puts out that
> fire," said Ron as they started up the staircase toward the silver
> ladder and the trapdoor. He was quite right. The dimly lit room was
> swelteringly hot. The fumes from the perfumed fire were heavier than
> ever.
>
> *Goblet of Fire: Chapter 29, The Dream*

Also, the students use spells to protect themselves against the weather when roaming around on castle grounds (eg. Hermione used to conjure small blue fire which can be carried in a Jar).

> do the fireplaces put out heat or is Floo Powder different due to
> people coming in or making personal calls?

Even if the fireplaces are used from time to time for travelling and communication (using floo powder), it doesn't mean that it cannot be used as a regular fireplace to provide heating.

Comment: Blame it on the wu, wu wu wu wu wizardry.

Comment: We should have Standard Answers. Standard Answer #1 is "Magic, my child, magic."

Answer (score -2):

Hogwarts probably just has fireplaces but people could just get torches and cast "incendio" and put the torch near their bed somewhere safe and away from their curtains and stuff.